# Significato di "v'appagate" in questo passaggio

Tags: meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Oh descriver potrò mai quel teatro, la spaventosa scena paratasi davanti su per le strade, i piani di quel borgo? Il genio mi ci vorrìa dell'Alighieri, dell'Astigian la foga, del Foscolo o del Byron la vena, dell'anglo tragediante, dell'angelo britanno il foco o la fiammante daga che scioglie d'in sul becco delle penne le chine raggelate per l'orrore, o del D'Azeglio o Vittor Hugo o del Guerrazzi almen la prosa larga... Di me, lasso!, che natura di fame, di fralezza e di baragli ha corredato, **v'appagate**?

Si tratta di un testo con un linguaggio volutamente ottocentesco perché è parte di una lunga lettera che scrive il barone di Mandralisca.

Ho cercato il verbo "appagare" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che significa "rendere pago, soddisfatto", ma non riesco a capire il senso di questo "v'appagate" che appare in questo passaggio. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: Vi accontentate?

Comment: Vi basta? Vi è sufficiente?

Comment: Cioè, il significato sarebbe "vi accontentate", "vi basta", "vi è sufficiente" questo mio povero modo di scrivere che è tanto diverso di quello di quegli autori che ho citato? Ha perfettamente senso.

Comment: Proprio così. Volendolo “costruire” la frase in modo più moderno sarebbe «v'appagate (accontentate) di me che la natura ha corredato (dotato) di fame (probabilmente anche nel senso di mancanza), fralezza (debolezza) e baragli (boh)?», cioè «vi accontentate di un poveraccio come me?».

Comment: Capisco, @DaG. Potresti metterelo come risposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il senso base di “appagare” è “accontentare, soddisfare”.

Qui, volendo “costruire” la frase in modo più moderno, avremmo qualcosa come «v'appagate (accontentate) di me che la natura ha corredato (dotato) di fame (probabilmente anche nel senso di mancanza), fralezza (debolezza) e baragli?», cioè, semplificando, «vi accontentate di un poveraccio come me (anziché di Dante e soci)?».

“Baragli” dovrebbe essere un sicilianismo per “sbadigli” (e quindi lo scrivente si considera anche noioso), come riportato nel [vocabolario siciliano - italiano](https://giuseppe-tuccio.jimdo.com/vocabolario-siciliano-italiano/lettera-b-parte-2/) segnalato da @Charo.

Comment: Mi sa che "baraglio" è una parola che avevo trovato pochi giorni fa su [questo dizionario](http://www.unice.fr/lirces/langues/real/dialectes/index.htm#Pour_consulter_le_dictionnaire:_) che, purtroppo, adesso non funziona più. Non riuscivo a ricordare il significato, ma adesso ho trovato su questo [vocabolario siciliano - italiano](https://giuseppe-tuccio.jimdo.com/vocabolario-siciliano-italiano/lettera-b-parte-2/) che "baragliu" significa "sbadiglio".

Comment: Ah, effettivamente ha senso: lo integro nella risposta.